# User profile fields: Get count of fields with value XYZ

Tags: views, 8

All user profiles contain these fields:

- **field_age** (integer)
- **field_category** (list: "Category A", "Category B", …, "Category Z")

I want to get the number of users with the value "Category A", "Category B" etc. for the landing page.

**How can I get the count of users for each answer?** I want to display the number on the landing page for every visitor.

---

The data **does not need to be live data**. It may be read from a file that is re-generated every 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view as a block using users as the base table (Structure>Views>Add View and set show=Users and check "Create a Block").  Then turn aggregation on in the advanced settings. Then add the field_category field and select "Group Field". Next add field_category a second time and select "Count". This should give you a column of each category, and the count of how many users exist in each category.

Finally, add the block to the frontpage in the Block Layout.